# Django Rest Framework unique together validation with field absent from request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm implementing some voting functionality in an application, where a logged-in user specifies a post that they would like to vote for using a payload like this:

```
{
  "post": 1,
  "value": 1
}
```

As you can tell, the a `user` field is absent - this is because it gets set in my viewset's `perform_create` method. I've done this to ensure the vote's `user` gets set server side. This is what the viewset looks like:

```
class CreateVoteView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = VoteSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Here is what the model looks like:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='votes', null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='votes', null=False)

    class Values(models.IntegerChoices):
        UP = 1, _('Up')
        DOWN = -1, _('Down')

    value = models.IntegerField(choices=Values.choices, null=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('post', 'user')
```

and finally, the serializer:

```
class VoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Vote
        fields = ['post', 'value']
```

From what I understand, in order for DRF to enforce a unique together validation, both fields (in my case, `user` and `post`) must be included in the serializer's `fields`. As I've mentioned, I'd like to avoid this. Is there any other way of implementing this type of validation logic?

EDIT:

To clarify: the records do not save - I receive this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1-3' for key 'api_vote.api_vote_post_id_user_id_73614533_uniq'")
```

However, my goal is to return a `Bad Request` instead of an `Internal Server Error` much like I would when traditionally using a DRF serializer and excluding required fields from a payload.

Comment: Can't replicate this. What `rest-framework` version are you using?

Comment: @drec4s 3.11.0 - can you describe the behaviour you're seeing?

Comment: I am also using version 3.11, and getting an `IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: vote.post_id, vote.user_id`

Comment: @drec4s I've updated my post for clarity. My aim is to gracefully handle these errors instead of returning a 500 to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To output a custom error message due to the `IntegrityError`, you can override the `create` method in your serializer:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

class VoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Vote
        fields = ['post', 'value']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            validated_data['user'] = self.context['request'].user
            return super().create(validated_data)
        except IntegrityError:
            error_msg = {'error': 'IntegrityError message'}
            raise serializers.ValidationError(error_msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can try this on your views

```
try:
    MoviesWatchList.objects.create(user=request.user, content=movie)
    return response.Response({'message': f'{movie} added in watchlist.'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
except:
    return response.Response({'message': f'{movie} already added to watchlist.'}, status=status.HTTP_304_NOT_MODIFIED)
```